# Mathematical Methods on 2d Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, constructor

I am working on a data structures assignment, and the topic in question is 2d Arrays. I need to come up with methods for addition, scalar multiplication & transpose. This is what I have so far:

1. The addition method **works**, but doesn't return any value.
2. The scalar multiplication method **works**, but doesn't return any value.
3. The transpose function **doesn't work**.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** If I use the statementreturn grid; I get an error as I should returning a Matrix value. But I don't know how to do so.**
.

```
public class Matrix {
private int [][] grid

public Matrix() {
    grid = new int[3][3];
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++)
        for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
            grid[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
}
/**
 * Creates matrix of specified size with random values 0..9
 * @param size positive integer that represents the number of rows
 * and columns in the matrix
 */
public Matrix(int size) {
    grid = new int[size][size];
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
        for(int y=0; y<size; y++)
            grid[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
}
/** 
 * Creates a matrix of specified size with random values 0..9
 * @param rows number of rows in matrix
 * @param columns number of columns int matrix
 */
public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
    grid = new int[rows][columns];
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++)
        for(int y=0; y<columns; y++)
            grid[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
}
/**
 * @String formatted as an m x n matrix of m rows and 
 * n columns
 */
public String toString() {
    int rows = grid.length;
    int columns = grid[0].length;
    String table = new String("");
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++) {
        table = table + '|' + '\t';
        for(int y=0; y<columns; y++)
            table = table + grid[x][y] + '\t';
        table = table + '|' + '\n';
    }
    return table;
}
/**
 * @return true if number of rows equals number of columns
 */
public boolean isSquare() {
    return grid.length == grid[0].length;
}
/**
 * @param other another matrix to compare to this one
 * @return true if this matrix and the other have the same
 * number of rows and columns
 */
public boolean sameSize(Matrix other) {
    return grid.length == other.grid.length && 
            grid[0].length == other.grid[0].length;
}

public Matrix add (Matrix other) {
    if(sameSize(other)){
        for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
          for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
            grid[x][y] += other.grid[x][y];
        }
            return null;
        }
    else{
     System.out.println("Matrices are not of same size. Additional not possible");  
    return null;
    }

}

public Matrix scalarMultiply (int multiplier) {

 for ( int x=0; x<grid.length; x++ ) {
      for ( int y=0; y<grid[0].length; y++ ) {
         grid[x][y] = grid[x][y] * multiplier;
       }
    }
    return this;
}
 public Matrix transpose() {
 int[][] transpose= new int[3][3];
  for(int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
            transpose[y][x] = grid[x][y];
        }
  grid = transpose;
  return this;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    Matrix n = new Matrix((int)(Math.random()*5)+2);
    Matrix o = new Matrix(((int)(Math.random()*5)+2),
                        ((int)(Math.random()*5)+2));
    System.out.println ("First matrix:");
    System.out.print(m);
    System.out.println ("Second matrix:");
    System.out.println(n);
    System.out.println ("Third matrix:");
    System.out.println(o);
    if(m.sameSize(n))
        System.out.println("First two are the same size");
    else
        System.out.println("First two are not the same size");
    if(o.isSquare())
        System.out.println("All three are square matrices");
    else
        System.out.println("Only first two are square matrices");
    System.out.println ("Addition of matrices:");
    m.add(n);
    m.scalarMultiply(4);
    m.transpose();

}
```

}

Comment: You need to do serious debugging if your code is not behaving properly, and you should do this *before* posting a question here since it is your responsibility to first *find* your bug. If you've done this already, you've not shown evidence for this in your question and need to fix this. Please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem.

Comment: I have tried reading the pre and post condition material on other articles. But that hasn't been covered in my class yet, and I am not able to make sense of it. My code complies, but clearly the result is wrong.

Comment: Try reading your code. When I look at add, I see two places where you return null and no place you return anything else. I'd suspect the problem is the same in the other two locations, but it's not my job to dig through your code to find all the errors. Learn now how to use a debugger to step through your code, so you can see exactly what is (and is not) happening in it. It's never too early to learn to use the best tool a developer has in their toolbox for finding and fixing problems. *It compiles* simply means you have no syntax errors, not that you don't have logic errors.

Comment: If you don't understand what you should be doing, then the proper course of action is not to post a question here, but to get up with your instructor.

Comment: Also, think twice about naming both the function and it's main variable `transpose`. It makes your code ridiculously hard to read. Name the array something else.

Comment: @KenWhite If I use the statement return grid; I get an error as I should returning a Matrix value. But I don't know how to do so.

Comment: You need to ask your instructor for help with your assignment, as has been mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Check your methods what you are writing:
This will compare your looping variables x and y that you have used for rows and columns, if rows==column then it is square matrix.

```
boolean isSquare()
    {
    if(x==y){return true;}
    else 
false;
    }
```

Your add method is returning null as well that's you don't get anything in ans.
From transpose() method don't do:

```
**grid = transpose;
  return this;** 
instead
 **return grid[y][x];**
```